# New to tensors, having problems understanding some basics

Tags: tensors, dual-spaces, tensor-rank

I have some components of a contravariant rank two tensor with respect to the standard basis $\{ \boldsymbol{e_1}\ \boldsymbol{e_2} \}$ which are called $a^{ij}$. The task is to find the components $a_{ij}$ with respect to the dual basis of the standard basis.
The textbook solution to this one is:
$$\boldsymbol{A} = a^{ij}|\boldsymbol{e_i}\rangle\langle\boldsymbol{e_j}|=a^{ij}g_{ik}g_{lj}|\boldsymbol{e^k}\rangle\langle\boldsymbol{e^{l}}|= a_{kl}|\boldsymbol{e^k}\rangle\langle\boldsymbol{e^{l}}|$$ from which follow that $a_{kl} = a^{kl}$.

I get the part of using the metric tensors to lower the indices and the fact that $g_{ij} = \delta_{ij}$, but what I really struggle with is the first part of the calculation where it says:
$$\boldsymbol{A} = a^{ij}|\boldsymbol{e_i}\rangle\langle\boldsymbol{e_j}|$$
I honestly never saw this in my scriptum and have some troubles understanding the meaning of it. Does this equation just represent the fact that $\boldsymbol{A}$ is a linear combination of the components $a^{ij}$ and the basis vectors $\boldsymbol{e_1}$ and $\boldsymbol{e_2}$?.

Would be really cool if someone could help me out with this!

Comment: Hi Tom! Thanks for answering my question :) Am I right when I say that $E_{ij}$ is a projector or at least has something to do with it? Cause that seems awful similar.

Comment: Sry, just a follow up question if that would be true: I was told that a matrix $C$ can be written as the sum of the products of the eigenvalues with the associated projections. So if $|\boldsymbol{e_i}\rangle\langle\boldsymbol{e_j}|$ represents the projector, are the components $a_{ij}$ the eigenvalues of this matrix $C$? Or am I on the completely wrong path?

Comment: Im very sorry, but i misintrepreted what "rank" meant in this context (I didn't study differential geometry in english unfortunately). I deleted my other comment to not confuse other people reading this. Anyway, the spirit of my other comment is kind of still right - any linear map has a representative matrix $[A]_{B} = a_{ij}$ and if $B$ is an orthonormal basis, $a_{ij}$ is given by $a_{ij} = \langle e_{i} | A e_{j}  \rangle $ (using physicist conventions - the left entry is antilinear).

Comment: We can decompose $a_{ij}$ into a linear sum of the said matrices $E_{ij}$, each representing the linear map that takes the vector $e_i$ and sends it to the vector $e_j$ and sending all other vectors to $0$. Since our basis is orthonormal, $E_{ij}$ is equivalent to taking a vector $v$, calculating $\langle e_{i} | v \rangle$ and multiplying by $e_{j}$ - so if $v = a_{k} |e_{k} \rangle$ (using einstein summation),

Comment: $E_{ij} (v) = |e_{j}\rangle \langle e_{i} | v \rangle = |e_{j} \rangle a_{k} \langle e_{i} | e_{k} \rangle = a_{i} |e_j\rangle $, which (hopefully) makes clear the notation $E_{ij}  = |e_{j}\rangle \langle e_{i} |$. Regarding your second question, $E_{ij}$'s arent projections - projections are linear maps that act on their image like the identity function, which $E_{ij}$ obviously dont do for $i \neq j$.